# QTouch Matrix ATmega8 issues

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, touchscreen, capacitive

After trying a lot on QTouch Matrix for ATmega8,It didn't work for me. So sharing the trouble here.

I have taken reference from [this](http://svo.2.staticpublic.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/capsensor/index.en.html) beautiful article. Here he had provided a schematic and PCB design also. I have followed the same schematic and PCB layout, used same code for ATmega8 @16MHz crystal and with fuse bits: 0xc9ff, still it is not working at all. 
I got calibrating message on terminal, then after that, when I touch the Pad, it displays random numbers on terminal and that was only for three keys! others are not working.
also those three keys are not working covering with a plastic sheet.

If somebody can direct me towards right path and give some tips, it would be better for me to move ahead.
schematic diagram:
[image]
I have set up ATmega8 on General Purpose PCB. touch Pad is connected through jumper wires.Below are Images of the test setup.
MATRIX PAD:
[image]
MATRIX PAD Wiring:
[image]
TEST SET UP:
[image]
ATmega8 Board:
[image]

Comment: How much capacitance do you think those long wires can pick up?

Comment: Long wires may be the issue?

Comment: thanks Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams for the comment. there may be one of the problem, but I have read few lines from the article mentioned above, from which i inspired to do this , says:
"There's a little problem however. All AVR inputs are protected from overvoltage by the internal Shottky diodes which have very low bandgap of 0.2V. This puts a serious constraint on the design: |quant.suff | should be not above 0.2V, or nothing will work out at all."
Can anybody explain me this please?

Comment: I thing there is a PCB design fault. I am designing new layout for QTouch Matrix touch pad in altium design software.

Answer (score 3):

You have missed the jumpers to join "Y-wires".
If you look at page2 fig4 image closely and read the fig4 text in the:
[QMatrix™ Technology White Paper](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/qmatrix_white_paper_100.pdf)

[image]